# Seletor CSS alterando valor se contem um elemento

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ao optar por qualquer definição de seletor é possível setar estilos para cada elemento que esta é definido.

Minha duvida seria, em vez de selecionar um elemento e alterar propriedades para ele mesmo, escolheria buscar um elemento e se caso encontrar setar propriedades para outro elemento com uma classe pré definida.

Em resumo se `.area{}` contém `div .popup{}` area recebe `overflow: hidden`, senão `overflow auto`

Exemplificando no HTML:

```
<div class="area">
    <div class="popup"></div> <!-- contem entao: overflow: hidden -->
</div>

<div class="area"></div> <!-- nao contem entao: overflow: auto -->
<div class="popup"></div>
```

A barra de rolagem de `div .area` depende da `div .popup` para existir.

**:has** ou
**:contains**

Não são seletores validos.

claro que poderia ser controlado por JS, porem levo mais em conta o uso de estilização, ou se haver uma maneira mais correta de fazer isto também ta valendo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma usando somente `css` que possivelmente poderá resolver seu problema, serio a seguinte solução abaixo, usando o seletor `css3` `:empty`, que aplica um determinado `css` caso o elemento selecionado não tenha nenhum elemento filho contido dentro dele.

```css
.area {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
  /*contem entao: overflow: hidden*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.area:empty {
  background: #f00;
  /*nao contem entao: overflow: auto*/
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
    <div class="popup"></div> <!-- contem entao: overflow: hidden -->
</div>

<div class="area"></div> <!-- nao contem entao: overflow: auto -->
```

Pórem, essa solução pode resolver seu problema, mas só irá funcionar caso o elemento com `class` `.area`, sempre esteja vázio, sem nenhum sub-elemento dentro dele.

Contudo, caso a solução acima não atenda seu problema, não teria uma forma de fazer o que você quer somente usando `CSS2` ou `CSS3`. Pois atualmente o `css` não trabalha com seleção de parentes, possivelemnte isso pode vir a ser implementado nas próximas versões dele.

Então uma boa solução para o seu problema, seria utilizando `Javascript` e `jQuery`.

Abaixo segue um simples exemplo utilizando `jQuery`:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.area').each(function() {

    var child = $(this).children('.popup');
    
    if (child.length == 0) {
     $(this).addClass('has-no-popup');
    }

  });
  
});
```

```css
.area {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #bbb;
  /*contem entao: overflow: hidden*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-no-popup {
  background: #f00;
  /*nao contem entao: overflow: auto*/
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="area">
    <div class="popup"></div> <!-- contem entao: overflow: hidden -->
</div>

<div class="area"></div> <!-- nao contem entao: overflow: auto -->
```

Comment: pois bem, `:empty` não pode ser, por conta que, já esta sendo optado por uma classe no seletor, não por "algo", então, poderá ter mais elementos com outras classes não sendo a `.popup`

Comment: Então nesse caso, não daria para fazer isso que você quer somente usando css2 ou css3, sendo assim seria melhor você fazer com Javascript e jQuery.